# How can I get paid for my app's in-app purchase from Apple? (iOS iTunesConnect)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My app has in-app purchase, and 5 of my users made the purchase.

How can I retrieve this profit from Apple?

Is there any specific guideline to follow in order to get paid by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find specific guidelines in the [In-app Purchase FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html) from Apple in the section [Agreements, Tax and Banking Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-AGREEMENTS__TAX__AND_BANKING_INFORMATION).

For all technical details see the [Agreements, Tax and Banking Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ManagingContractsandBanking.html) in the ITunes developers guide.

> To sell apps through the App Store or Mac App Store, you provide
>   banking information so that Apple can pay you for apps sold. iTunes
>   Connect stores all the bank information you specify. However, only one
>   bank account is used for payments against all contracts. You can edit
>   or update banking information anytime. Banking updates made while
>   payments are in process are applied to the subsequent period’s
>   payments.
>
> For more information about banking issues, see “Banking and Tax” in
>   the iTunes Connect FAQ, available in the Resources and Help section of
>   iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1):

When you registered with iTunes Connect you had to fill in your bank account information. Once a month Apple will transfer the profits to this back account.

You can find this in the iTunes Connect *Agreements, Tax, and Banking* section. Here you can request the contract for paid apps, which include IAP.